# ActiveMQ 5.15.3 client shutdown hangs due to FailoverTransport

Tags: activemq-classic

Client runs within Spring: `JmsTemplate` with `PooledConnectionFactory` and `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`, with one `stop` method:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "stop", initMethod = "start")
public PooledConnectionFactory pullConnectionFactory() {
....
```

Sometimes during shutdown the JVM hangs, due to `FailoverTransport`. It tries to reconnect to ActiveMQ in infinitive loop. However it cannot reconnect, because all Connections are already down....

Has anyone experienced such issue?

Here is the log:

```
2019-04-15 13:25:11,712 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] INFO : org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@403455c[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 728] is shutdown: true and terminated: false took: 10.001 seconds.
2019-04-15 13:25:11,712 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport tcp://server1/10.173.117.58:61616@58016
2019-04-15 13:25:11,712 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1569cb5d[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2019-04-15 13:25:11,713 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
2019-04-15 13:25:11,713 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1569cb5d[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2019-04-15 13:25:11,714 [localhost-startStop-2] WARN : org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Transport (nio://server1:61616) failed , attempting to automatically reconnect: {}
org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://10.173.117.58:61616
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.doOnewaySend(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:328)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.oneway(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:317)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.oneway(TransportFilter.java:94)
.....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-04-15 13:25:11,715 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - urlList connectionList:[nio://server2:61616, nio://server1:61616], from: [nio://server1:61616, nio://server2:61616]
2019-04-15 13:25:11,716 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waiting 500 ms before attempting connection
2019-04-15 13:25:12,216 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting 0th connect to: nio://server2:61616
2019-04-15 13:25:12,220 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://server2:61616, reason: {}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-04-15 13:25:12,220 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport nio://server2:61616
2019-04-15 13:25:12,220 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6c0c966f[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2019-04-15 13:25:12,221 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
2019-04-15 13:25:12,221 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6c0c966f[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2019-04-15 13:25:12,222 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting 0th connect to: nio://server1:61616
2019-04-15 13:25:12,225 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator  - Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.15.3}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2019-04-15 13:25:22,225 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://server1:61616, reason: {}
java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.restoreTransport(FailoverTransport.java:851)
....
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-04-15 13:25:22,226 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport tcp://server1/10.173.117.58:61616@45708
2019-04-15 13:25:22,226 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@10da1f11[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2019-04-15 13:25:22,227 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
2019-04-15 13:25:22,227 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@10da1f11[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2019-04-15 13:25:22,227 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waiting 500 ms before attempting connection
2019-04-15 13:25:22,728 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - urlList connectionList:[nio://server2:61616, nio://server1:61616], from: [nio://server1:61616, nio://server2:61616]
2019-04-15 13:25:22,728 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting 1th connect to: nio://server2:61616
2019-04-15 13:25:22,730 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://server2:61616, reason: {}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
.....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-04-15 13:25:22,731 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport nio://server2:61616
2019-04-15 13:25:22,731 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4bbc5fc0[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2019-04-15 13:25:22,731 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
2019-04-15 13:25:22,732 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4bbc5fc0[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2019-04-15 13:25:22,732 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting 1th connect to: nio://server1:61616
2019-04-15 13:25:22,735 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator  - Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.15.3}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2019-04-15 13:25:32,735 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://server1:61616, reason: {}
java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:99)
....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-04-15 13:25:32,735 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport tcp://server1/10.173.117.58:61616@45820
2019-04-15 13:25:32,736 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@f8413d5[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2019-04-15 13:25:32,736 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
2019-04-15 13:25:32,737 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@f8413d5[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2019-04-15 13:25:32,737 [ActiveMQ Task-3] WARN : org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Failed to connect to [nio://server1:61616, nio://server2:61616] after: 2 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
2019-04-15 13:25:32,737 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waiting 500 ms before attempting connection
2019-04-15 13:25:33,237 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - urlList connectionList:[nio://server2:61616, nio://server1:61616], from: [nio://server1:61616, nio://server2:61616]
2019-04-15 13:25:33,237 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting 2th connect to: nio://server2:61616
2019-04-15 13:25:33,240 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://server2:61616, reason: {}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
.....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-04-15 13:25:33,241 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport nio://server2:61616
2019-04-15 13:25:33,241 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6d36d605[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2019-04-15 13:25:33,241 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
2019-04-15 13:25:33,241 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6d36d605[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2019-04-15 13:25:33,242 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting 2th connect to: nio://server1:61616
2019-04-15 13:25:33,244 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator  - Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.15.3}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2019-04-15 13:25:43,244 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://server1:61616, reason: {}
java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:99)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-04-15 13:26:57,319 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport nio://server2:61616
2019-04-15 13:26:57,319 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@25ce4335[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2019-04-15 13:26:57,320 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
2019-04-15 13:26:57,321 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@25ce4335[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2019-04-15 13:26:57,321 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting 10th connect to: nio://server1:61616
2019-04-15 13:26:57,323 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator  - Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.15.3}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2019-04-15 13:27:07,324 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://server1:61616, reason: {}
java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.restoreTransport(FailoverTransport.java:851)
.....
2019-04-15 13:27:07,324 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport tcp://server1/10.173.117.58:61616@46918
2019-04-15 13:27:07,325 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5c898e41[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2019-04-15 13:27:07,325 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
2019-04-15 13:27:07,325 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5c898e41[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2019-04-15 13:27:07,326 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waiting 500 ms before attempting connection
2019-04-15 13:27:07,826 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - urlList connectionList:[nio://server2:61616, nio://server1:61616], from: [nio://server1:61616, nio://server2:61616]
2019-04-15 13:27:07,826 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting 11th connect to: nio://server2:61616
2019-04-15 13:27:07,829 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://server2:61616, reason: {}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:111)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:525)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.NIOTransport.doStart(NIOTransport.java:174)
.....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-04-15 13:27:07,829 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport nio://server2:61616
2019-04-15 13:27:07,829 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@45fafa6a[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2019-04-15 13:27:07,830 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
2019-04-15 13:27:07,830 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@45fafa6a[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2019-04-15 13:27:07,830 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting 11th connect to: nio://server1:61616
2019-04-15 13:27:07,832 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator  - Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.15.3}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2019-04-15 13:27:17,833 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://server1:61616, reason: {}
java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.restoreTransport(FailoverTransport.java:851)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.doReconnect(FailoverTransport.java:1020)
....
2019-04-15 13:27:17,833 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Stopping transport tcp://server1/10.173.117.58:61616@47028
2019-04-15 13:27:17,833 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory  - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@536d6ce[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2019-04-15 13:27:17,834 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport  - Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
2019-04-15 13:27:17,834 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.util.ThreadPoolUtils  - Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@536d6ce[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2019-04-15 13:27:17,835 [ActiveMQ Task-3] WARN : org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Failed to connect to [nio://server1:61616, nio://server2:61616] after: 12 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
2019-04-15 13:27:17,835 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Waiting 500 ms before attempting connection
2019-04-15 13:27:18,335 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - urlList connectionList:[nio://server2:61616, nio://server1:61616], from: [nio://server1:61616, nio://server2:61616]
2019-04-15 13:27:18,335 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Attempting 12th connect to: nio://server2:61616
2019-04-15 13:27:18,337 [ActiveMQ Task-3] DEBUG: org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport  - Connect fail to: nio://server2:61616, reason: {}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FailoverTransport is configured to retry indefinitely, so you must set the maxReconnectAttempts to > 0. Some more info here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-9216. You can set it on the serverURL like this: https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/activemq/content/5.7.0/failover-transport-reference.html

Comment: I've implemented a shutdown hook, that sets failover to 1 on shutdown, this solved my problem, so your answer conforms it.

Answer (score 1):

- I have attempted most of these suggestions, and the `org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor` messages keep-on coming.
- More embaressing (for me) is that my app is a simple Jave command line program to just send one (or more) files.
- When the `main(...)` method exits, the ActiveMQ log keeps on printing.

  - Eventhough the program has (supposedly) terminated

  ```
    14:20:15.686 INFO  a.c.f.f.e.MqDriver - MqDriver.main...  MQ driver --  DONE.

    14:20:35.667 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10000ms elapsed since last write check.
    14:20:35.693 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
    14:20:45.667 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker: 10000ms elapsed since last write check.
    14:20:45.667 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
    14:20:55.667 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - 30000ms elapsed since last read check.
       :
  ```
- So far I have not found a way to shutdown an ActiveMQ clinet-side threadpool; still looking.
- Did find that everything stops when you call `System.exit( exitCode )` at the end of `main(...)`

  ```
    14:35:47.686 INFO  a.c.f.f.e.MqDriver - MqDriver.main...  MQ driver --  DONE.

  MqDriver $
  ```

Back to he command line, ActiveMQ logging is finished.  Perhaps that is the deliberate intention for stopping a client.  I don't really expect that though.

Make sure you call `System.exit( exitCode )` or `System.exit( 0 )` if you have threads running.  Of course, call the `Executor` class `shutdown()` method first where you can.  Keep things *tidy*.